# Ferromagnet induced current?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A ferromagnet is attracted to a solenoid's magnetic field. I understand that now the ferromagnet produced a magnetic field, from that process is there an induced $EMF$?

Can ferromagnets that are not permanent magnets( i.e low magnetic remanence ) induced $EMF$ in the solenoid?

Answer (score 1):

> A ferromagnet is attracted to a solenoid's magnetic field.

By this I hope you mean there is already current in the solenoid. Then as you are saying magnet is attracted towards the solenoid's magnetic field, for this to happen we can have two cases.

The two cases are:
1.Current in the solenoid is clockwise (viewed from the lefft or right side, say left side) then it is attracting north pole of ferromagnet or otherwise
2.Current in the solenoid is anticlockwise (say when viewed from left side), then it is attracting north pole of the ferromagnet.

Remember ferromagnets are those substances (iron, nickel, cobalt, alnico, etc), which when placed in a magnetic field are strongly magnetised *in the direction of the magnetising field*. This means ferromanets are attracted by magnetic field. In case of solenoid, if current is in clock wise direction then it acts as the south pole and vice versa. In case of  ferromagnets we can't initially speak about poles, but I have spoke about poles of ferromagnetic material. As known ferromagnets are attracted to the field of solenoid then side approaching solenoid should have opposite polarity, so I have assigned the poles accordingly. If you have any confusion here, you can comment.

> I understand that now the ferromagnet produced a magnetic field,

Due to solenoids magnetic field (or external magnetic field), the magnetic fields of the individual domains tend to line up in the direction of this external field, thus there will be magnetic field created around them. Remember, the polarity of ferromagnet's side near the solenoid will be opposite to the polarity of solenoid's approximated circular face, because it is what causes it to get attracted.

> from that process *is there an induced $EMF$*?

Yes, there will be induced $EMF$, but $EMF$ induced produces current in the opposite direction of the current in the solenoid (lenz's law) when brought near the solenoid. This will cause charge accumulation in the solenoid (against the significance of kirchoff's junction rule). I will not speak about $EMF$ induced when ferromagnet is with drawn as we are speaking about the case where ferromagnet is attracted not repulsed.

> Can ferromagnets that are not permanent magnets( i.e low magnetic remanence ) induced EMF in the solenoid?

As said above, if there is solenoids magnetic field, ferromagnets can induce $EMF$. If you are speaking about the situation where the solenoids has no current through it and you want to induce current, it will not be possible. Because, there will be no magnetic field around the ferromagnetic substance with out the solenoids magnetic field which could induce $EMF$ in the solenoid. If ferromagnet has some remanent magnetization, it could not induce much $EMF$.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. However, lets assume two cases, where Faraday's law is applied. A permanent magnet is attracted to a solenoid, and a ferromagnet is attracted to the solenoid, BOTH cases produce EMF(Voltage) that opposes the input voltage applied on the Solenoid? Faraday's law of induction is applied to ferromagnets moving in and out of a functioning Solenoid?! That is mind boggling...

Comment: I think Faraday's law is not confined to ferromagnet situation considered in the above question. Actually we always speak about permanent magnets in case of Faraday's experiments related to inducing emf.

Comment: However, some would argue that ferromagnet's would cause change in flux of the electromagnet's magnetic field. Thus inducing EMF, yet I just can NOT picture it...

Comment: Imagine a large electromagnet that pulls iron from a distance, do you think there will be -V induced within the coils?

Comment: I hope you are saying that electromagnet pulls a iron bar towards the coil with no current. In that case, no, I don't think there will be induced emf. If pulled iron bar gets magnatised due to electromagnet there will be chances of slight induced emf. But, iron getting magnetised in short interval of time is a far thing to happen.

Comment: "But, iron getting magnetised in short interval of time is a far thing to happen" please explain a bit more.

Comment: Hi, I have read your answer. I haven't understood your last point: "about the situation where the solenoids has no current through it and you want to induce current, it will not be possible. Because, there will be no magnetic field around the ferromagnetic substance with out the solenoids magnetic field which could induce EMF in the solenoid. If ferromagnet has some remanent magnetization, it could not induce much EMF". Please, could you explain me why the remanent magnetizazion could induce EMF? Thanks a lot!